# How import RAML latest version in mule application?

Tags: mule, raml

I have a RAML with one get endpoint. Import this RAML in mule app. Now i have api router kit with one get endpoint.
If i have update my RAML and add new POST endpoint, then how i can import latest RAML in existing mule application.

Comment: Can you clarify if you have updated the RAML in design center and published to exchange? Or are you importing by downloading and copying the raml in your project resources folder?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the RAML in design center and published to exchange. When I was trying to update api using API Specs > update version, the RAML file was not updating automatically, but the new flow was created. 

That's why I was getting 404 for new endpoint. But I have manually update the RAML in mule application and my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions to update an API specification in a project are explained in the documentation page https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/7.12/sync-update-api-spec:

> To update the API specification:
>
> 1. In the Package Explorer view, right-click the Mule project that contains the API specification you want to update.
> 2. Select API Specs > the name of your API > Update Version. After you update the specification, Studio asks you if you want to
>    regenerate the flows based on the new version.
>
> To manually generate a flow for the updated API, right-click the Mule
> project where you updated the API specification, and select API Specs
> the name of your API > Generate Flows.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you answer "yes" when it asks you if you want to regenerate the flows, then you don't need to do the manual "Generate Flows" step.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Updated RAML new flow was auto generated when i update api version using API Specs , but still new endpoint showing 404. When i update RAML file manually in my application, my issue was resolved.

Any idea about this? Why the RAML file was not updating automatically?